# CPU Fan not working on acer 4755G i3 ubuntu 12.10

Tags: acer, cpu, overheating, temperature

Hope you can help me, I'm new to ubuntu and install this 12.10 version on my acer laptop. The problem is I always got high temperature and maybe because my CPU fan is not working. Tried to install acerhdf but unfortunately it says unsupported bios. The temp I always got is 75 and higher and when I tried to open youtube or play any music and videos, my system restart. I also found out that this laptop doesn't support linux according to their site. So if you could help me it would be great, and if there is no solution to this then maybe I'll try other platform.

Thank you..

Comment: Fans are controlled by the hardware/firmware, so you should check with the manufacturer for a bios update.

Comment: I actually check the site for the bios update, but on their update it seems it only support windows 7 and 8 for it.

Answer (score 0):

i used to have this problem on my acer aspire 5720z

i could get the fan to work by logging into the computer then putting it to sleep then turn it on and unlock it and the fan would turn on they fixed the problem a couple weeks later in an update

try this

if it doesnt work try to re-install windows on it (if you have a disk) if you don't then try the recovery oem partition (you may need to look up the button you press while the computer turns on)